# Criar varias senhas para diferentes usuarios

Tags: html5

estou usando esse código em java:

```
<script language="javascript">
    <!--
    function Senha() {
    var password = "123"
    var pass = prompt("OlÃ¡ Patrocinador, coloque sua senha."," ")
    if (pass.toLowerCase() == password) {
    window.location = "https://www88.zippyshare.com/v/lLEMO0ln/file.html";
    }
    else {
    window.location = "https://i.ibb.co/0tRny72/SEJA-UM-PATROCINADOR.png";
    }
    }
    -->
    </script>
```

para poder ser exibida apenas para usuarios que tenham a senha. Gostaria de saber se é possivel criar nesse código varias senhas.

estou aplicando isso no blogger

Answer (score -1):

Poderia fazer um array com as senhas que você quer utilizar e fazer a validação com ele. Outra opção seria cada usuário ter uma senha e você armazenar os dados numa API e para validação fazer uma request.